# Assigning date to a cell in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am just trying to enter the current date into a cell through excel vba macro.

Following is the code for the same.

```
Cells(i,j).value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Its giving me

> Application-defined OR Object defined error

Answer (score 0):

```
Cells(i,j).value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems nice. However, the problem is probably that you do not declare the activesheet. Or see what are the values of `i` and `j`:

```
debug.print i; j
ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j).value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

or

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(i,j).value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

See a bit about the range object here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since the proposed methods doesn't work for me, I found another solution:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i,j).Value2 = Date
```